# unable to click and select a value from a drop down of a pop up using protractor.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, gulp-protractor, protractor-net

I am using protractor.js. Using which I am able to login to my application. But after immediate login, there will be a pop up and I need to select a drop down value from it. but using protractor.js I was unable to do that. The code is mentioned below.

```
  describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
      it('should add a todo', function() {
          browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('https://sample.com');

        //browser.waitForAngular();
        //browser.sleep(10000);
         browser.pause();
        element(by.id('userId')).sendKeys('johny.selvaraj@test.com');
        browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5000);
        element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('*********');
        browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5000);
        **element(by.className('id-login-button wk-button-primary wk-button-full')).click();**
        //browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5000);
         //browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
         browser.sleep(20000);
        browser.switchTo().defaultContent();

         browser.wait( done => {  
         return element(by.model('productSelectionCtrl.selectedProduct')).isPresent();
         })
         .then(()=>{
         element(by.model('productSelectionCtrl.selectedProduct')).click();
         element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Master Suite')).click();
         browser.sleep(20000);

         done;
         });

      });

    });
```

My code is working until the line which is made bold. After thet , I took the class name of the pop up to be clicked and needed to select a value "Master suite" from the drop down which has ng-model(productSelectionCtrl.selectedProduct). But this is not done. Can you please help me with this.

I even tried by using (browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;) since my home page is angular page,but resulted in vain. Please help me to select a value from that drop down. Maybe the issue is with wait or timeout.The error I get in the console is mentioned below.

```
Failures:
1) angularjs homepage todo list should add a todo
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:232:11)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 36.928 seconds

[18:20:14] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[18:20:14] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[18:20:14] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[18:20:14] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `by.className` expects a *single class name*. If you want to use multiple classes, use a *CSS selector* locator:

```
$('.id-login-button.wk-button-primary.wk-button-full').click();
```

Note that, if you would have used `ESLint` and `eslint-plugin-protractor` plugin (absolutely shameless self-promotion), you could have caught this error much earlier - there is a relevant [`no-compound-classes`](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/no-compound-classes.md) rule.

As a side note, try to avoid using `browser.sleep()` and instead use [`browser.wait()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) and a set of built-in [*Expected Conditions*](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions).

Comment: The line $('.id-login-button.wk-button-primary.wk-button-full').click(); worked which is the element for login button. The code after this doesn't work.The ng-model name of the pop up is "productSelectionCtrl.selectedProduct" and the code after this is for the drop down

Comment: @johny please try avoid solving multiple follow-up problems in the same topic. Instead, if you think we've solved your current problem, please accept the answer (green checkbox on the left). If you have any follow-up issues, consider creating a separate topic. Thanks.

Comment: its not a follow up problem. In the main question itself I have mentioned like "My code is working until the line which is made bold. After that , I took the class name of the pop up to be clicked and needed to select a value "Master suite" from the drop down which has ng-model(productSelectionCtrl.selectedProduct). But this is not done. Can you please help me with this." And the bold line of code is the clicking of  login button which works already.So please help me with this.